# Prove that it is always possible to have solution of $2^k - a\cdot m = n$ when $k\ge 0, a \ge 0$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n) = 2^x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm, coding-theory

I recently encountered a [coding question](https://leetcode.com/problems/check-if-point-is-reachable/description) which I was not able to solve but when I saw other's solution then I found out that they are using GCD property to deduce optimized solution.

Below is the problem statement.

> There exists an infinitely large grid. You are currently at point (1,
> 1), and you need to reach the point (targetX, targetY) using a finite
> number of steps.
>
> In one step, you can move from point (x, y) to any one of the
> following points:
>
> - (x, y - x)
> - (x - y, y)
> - (2 * x, y)
> - (x, 2 * y)
>
> Given two integers targetX and targetY representing the X-coordinate and Y-> coordinate of your final position, return true if
> you can reach the point from (1, 1) using some number of steps, and
> false otherwise.

**Accepted Solution:**

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isReachable(int targetX, int targetY) {
        int gcd = gcd(targetX, targetY);
        return (gcd & (gcd - 1)) == 0;
    }

    int gcd(int x, int y) {
        if (x < y) return gcd(y, x);
        if (y == 0) return x;
        return gcd(y, x % y);
    }
}
```

So basically solution exists only if $GCD(targetX, targetY) = 2^k, k >= 0$.

I asked for the proof $2^k - a\cdot m = n$ when $k\ge 0, a \ge 0$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n) = 2^x$ because we can always go to the point $(m, 1)$ from point $(1,1)$ but to go to the point $(m, n)$ from there we will need to prove the above statement.

I am not able to understand why this is necessary and sufficient condition?

Can someone please add a proof of this along with some intuition.

Comment: Bézout's lemma says that there are always integers $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)=\alpha\cdot m+\beta \cdot n.$ So $\beta\cdot n=2^k-\alpha\cdot m.$

Comment: @MariusS.L. thanks for pointing out to the theory related to this. It is very hard to come up with these kinds of solution or even understand these kinds of solution without having fundamentals of mathematics clear. Can you provide me the link to some course/resource which I can follow for atleast the mathematics required for CS.

Comment: When it comes to integers, then it is often the Euclidean algorithm that comes into play. It simply says: given to integers $a,b$, then there are integers $q,r$ such that $a=q\cdot b +r$ with $0\leq r<b.$ That is the division of $a$ by $b$ with remainder $r.$ Since $r<b$ we can go on with $b=q'\cdot r+r'$ and $0\leq r' <r.$ This procedure ends when the remainder is zero. If you apply it where $d=\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$ then you end up with an equation $d=\alpha\cdot a+\beta\cdot b.$ It is simple division. You could try to apply it for your situation here.

Comment: The thing is: we are not allowed to divide within the integers, so we have to write it out and manage what otherwise was a quotient. $\frac{a}{b}=q$ becomes $a=q\cdot b$ and this is an equation that is allowed in the integers. It is also good to keep this in mind for programming. Every division is an approximation and creates an error. $a=q\cdot b$ is exact. Divide at the end once if you need to, but do not accumulate errors during the algorithm.

Comment: @MariusS.L.  for $ ⋅  = 2^ −  ⋅ $ can we say there will always be some  if $ = 1$?

Comment: No. You can only say that there are such $\alpha,\beta$ if $\operatorname{gcd}(n,m)=2^k.$ You cannot set $\beta=1.$ I'm not sure you even need that. You haven't made full advantage of all steps. Your solution is only one possibility. I guess any other value of $\beta$ has another solution.

Comment: But I want to get $n$ using that equation. Only that is required for the solution.

Comment: So what are the variables, and what are the parameters? You can't have a solution for $2^2-a\cdot 7=9.$ And before you complain: $\operatorname{gcd}(7,9)=1=2^0$ and $x=0$ is allowed.

Comment: Coming to your example $2^2 - a . 7 = 9$ yes we can't have solution for this. But if you see the problem statement then we don't have any constraint upon $2^k$, k can be anything greater than 0. So we can solve for $(7,9)$ as $2^4 - 1 . 7 = 9$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rephrase the problem as follows. We have four allowed transformations to get away from point $(x,y).$
\begin{align*}
A\, &: \,\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y-x\end{pmatrix}\\[8pt]
B\, &: \,\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x-y\\y\end{pmatrix}\\[8pt]
C\, &: \,\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2x\\y\end{pmatrix}\\[8pt]
D\, &: \,\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\2y\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Any path from $(1,1)$ to $(x,y)$ is $P(1,1)^T=(x,y)^T$ where $P$ is a word over the alphabet $A,B,C,D,$ i.e. any finite product of these four matrices. It is immediately clear that every path has a determinant $2^k$ for some non-negative integer $k$ depending on the number of matrices $C,D$ in $P.$

Let $P=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}.$ Then $a+b=x\, , \,c+d=y\, , \,ad-bc=2^k.$

We have now a word problem, so ordering the matrices within $P$ could be the next step. I would start with $C$ and $D$ and pull them at the beginning of $P.$

Another possibility is to prove that all values $a,b,c,d$ can be reached as long as the determinant $ad-bc$ is a power of two.